# Getting data iterating over wtform fields

Tags: jquery, python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I've got a form, and number of dynamically adding fields,

```
class EditBook(Form):
    title = TextField('title', validators = [Required()])
    authors = FieldList(TextField())
```

that's how I append them

```
$('form').append('<input type="text" class="span4" id="authors-' + FieldCount +'" name="authors-' + FieldCount +'" placeholder="author ' + FieldCount +'">');
```

I want to get data from theese inputs. how can I iterate over them, using python?

(or how can I send collected data with jquery to server? I'm new to js and jquery)

guess my inputs aren't connected with authors Fieldlist.

**UPDATE**

my inputs aren't connected with EditBook though I append them to it.

form.data will solve rest of the problem, when I attach my inputs to form. (now I just get keyerror, trying to access form.data['authors-1'])

now I try to add just a single authors field to copy it later.
but it renders invisible, for unknown reason.
in blank space should be input, similar to "author-1"

```
{{form.authors(class="span4", placeholder="author 1")}}
```

what should I add to code to render this field correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **WTForms** `process_formdata` method will pull these out of the form submission and store them in the `data` attribute. Below is what your access code will look like. Your `authors` list should be stored in an iterable that can be accessed with the `authors` key.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from wtforms.validators import Required
from wtforms import Form
from wtforms import TextField
from wtforms import FieldList

from webob.multidict import MultiDict

class EditBook(Form):
    title = TextField('title', validators = [Required()])
    authors = FieldList(TextField())

Book = namedtuple('Book', ['title', 'authors'])
b1 = Book('Title1', ['author1', 'author2'])

# drop them in a dictionary 
data_in={'title':b1.title, 'authors':b1.authors}

# Build form and print
form = EditBook(data=MultiDict(data_in))

# lets get some data
print form.data
print form.data['title']
print form.data['authors']
```

Comment: my inputs aren't connected with EditBook though I append them to it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. HTTP is stateless. This answer mocks out what happens when you POST. The POST happens after you've dynamically added the `author` inputs. If your `author` values aren't in the request then something is wrong on the browser end.

Answer (score 0):

The Form object is iterable and returns its fields so:

```
for f in form:
  print(f"{f.id}: {f.data}")
```